# iOS: plist inheritance

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I have an iOS app with multiple targets - a target for the developer and enterprise programs.

My app needs to access some different properties depending on the target.
I configured the targets to package separate plist files via Target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist File).

Most properties are common between the 2 plist files but a few are different.

**Can plists inherit from a common parent plist? I would like to reduce duplication in plist files if possible.**

Comment: plists are just XML files. This should answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think plists can have a "parent", they're just a file type... If you don't want to go through the trouble of copying everything and changing the few differences, though, you can open it up in a text editor like Sublime and directly edit the XML. That way you can command f whatever you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The goal is to maintain a plist with no duplication. Can I leave the common properties in a common plist but move the non-common stuff to the respective target or configuration?

Comment: plists can't inherit any properties, but one way you could sort of do this is by making the main plist, then another plist with the extra properties and parsing both in the code.

Comment: I believe this article outlines the approach you suggested:
http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/06/20/managing-ios-configurations-per-environment-in-xcode-4/

Comment: The link isn't loading :(

Comment: Link again:
[link](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/06/20/managing-ios-configurations-per-environment-in-xcode-4/)